# PWAのWebPUSH受信する際の通信経路を確認したい

Tags: javascript

Reactで動くPWAのWebアプリを開発しています。
このWebアプリはAndroidのChromeで動作し、WebPUSHを受信することができます。
Webアプリ（SPA）をホスティングしており、
サブスクリプションを保存するDBと疎通し、WebPUSHを行うAPIサーバがあります。

手元のAndroid端末で正しく動くことを確認済です。

次に、もう一台のAndroid端末のChromeで動作を確認した所
WebPUSHを受信することができませんでした。
接続できなかった端末は、許可された通信のみ使用が可能となっており
Webアプリをホストしているドメインと
サブスクリプションを保存するDBと疎通し、WebPUSHを行うAPIサーバ、
WebPUSHに使う、エンドポイントであるfcm.googleapis.comを許可しています。
PUSH処理を行った場合、APIサーバからPUSH処理を行い、fcm.googleapis.comまではアクセスできていることを確認済です。

正常に動く端末と、問題のある端末に差は無く（OSバージョン、Chromeバージョンが同一）
違いが、接続制限の有無のみと仮定した場合

一つの可能性として
fcm.googleapis.comから、問題のある端末への接続が
ブロックされているのでは？と考えているのですが
エンドポイントからChromeブラウザの通信は、どのように行われており
また、特定の通信として許可できるものであったりするのでしょうか？